# Host address of Hotmail and Yahoo! on IMAP

Tags: imap

How I can configure my Yahoo! and Hotmail account to use IMAP?

Answer (score 3):

Yahoo! Mail does have IMAP at `imap.mail.yahoo.com`, but you have to send a nonstandard command pre-login, namely `ID ("GUID" "1")`. There are some modified clients available to do this, you can find some [here](http://www.crasseux.com/linux/).

Hotmail does not have IMAP, but does have POP3 available at `pop3.live.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Hotmail nor Yahoo! Mail provide IMAP service.

---

Hotmail *does* have POP3 at `pop3.live.com` (over SSL on standard POP3/SSL port), but it is very limited in comparison to IMAP.